# Grails - when saving domain objects - i am getting "rejected value [null] error"

Tags: java, grails, orm, grails-orm

I have three domain objects defined as :

```
class Member {
    String name

    static constraints = {}
    static belongsTo=[community:Community]
}

class Community {
    String leaderName
    String code

    static constraints = {}
    static hasMany=[members: Member]
    static belongsTo=[bank:Bank]
}

class Bank {

    String bankName
    static hasMany=[communities: Community]
    static constraints = {}
}
```

When I tried to initialize these domain objects with some test data in `BootStrap.groovy` config class as :

```
 def init = { servletContext ->

            def m1 = new Member(name:"M1_Name")
            def m2 = new Member(name:"M2_Name")
            def m3 = new Member(name:"M3_Name")

            m1.save(failOnError:true)
            m2.save(failOnError:true)
            m3.save(failOnError:true)

            def comA = new Community(leaderName:"LeaderA", code:"AA")
            def comB = new Community(leaderName:"LeaderB", code:"BB")

            comA.addToMembers(m1)
            comA.addToMembers(m2)
            comB.addToMembers(m3)

            comA.save(failOnError:true)
            comB.save(failOnError:true)

            def bankA = new Bank(bankName:"BankA")
            def bankB = new Bank(bankName:"BankB")

            bankA.addToCommunities(comA)
            bankB.addToCommunities(comB)

            bankA.save(failOnError:true)
            bankB.save(failOnError:true)
        }
```

I am getting following error :

```
| Loading Grails 2.0.4
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Compiling 3 source files.....
| Running Grails application
| Error 2012-07-13 22:14:44,798 [pool-5-thread-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Validation Error(s) occurred during save():
- Field error in object 'mygrailtests.Member' on field 'community': rejected value [null]; codes [mygrailtests.Member.community.nullable.error.mygrailtests.Member.community,mygrailtests.Member.community.nullable.error.community,mygrailtests.Member.community.nullable.error.mygrailtests.Community,mygrailtests.Member.community.nullable.error,member.community.nullable.error.mygrailtests.Member.community,member.community.nullable.error.community,member.community.nullable.error.mygrailtests.Community,member.community.nullable.error,mygrailtests.Member.community.nullable.mygrailtests.Member.community,mygrailtests.Member.community.nullable.community,mygrailtests.Member.community.nullable.mygrailtests.Community,mygrailtests.Member.community.nullable,member.community.nullable.mygrailtests.Member.community,member.community.nullable.community,member.community.nullable.mygrailtests.Community,member.community.nullable,nullable.mygrailtests.Member.community,nullable.community,nullable.mygrailtests.Community,nullable]; arguments [community,class mygrailtests.Member]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null]

Message: Validation Error(s) occurred during save():
- Field error in object 'mygrailtests.Member' on field 'community': rejected value [null]; codes [mygrailtests.Member.community.nullable.error.mygrailtests.Member.community,mygrailtests.Member.community.nullable.error.community,mygrailtests.Member.community.nullable.error.mygrailtests.Community,mygrailtests.Member.community.nullable.error,member.community.nullable.error.mygrailtests.Member.community,member.community.nullable.error.community,member.community.nullable.error.mygrailtests.Community,member.community.nullable.error,mygrailtests.Member.community.nullable.mygrailtests.Member.community,mygrailtests.Member.community.nullable.community,mygrailtests.Member.community.nullable.mygrailtests.Community,mygrailtests.Member.community.nullable,member.community.nullable.mygrailtests.Member.community,member.community.nullable.community,member.community.nullable.mygrailtests.Community,member.community.nullable,nullable.mygrailtests.Member.community,nullable.community,nullable.mygrailtests.Community,nullable]; arguments [community,class mygrailtests.Member]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null]

   Line | Method
->>  13 | doCall                           in BootStrap$_closure1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   301 | evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock in grails.util.Environment
|   294 | executeForEnvironment . . . . .  in     ''
|   270 | executeForCurrentEnvironment     in     ''
|   303 | innerRun . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run                              in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run                              in     ''
^   662 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

Here, line 13 is

```
m1.save(failOnError:true)
```

Could you please suggest me what's wrong going on? Or what I am missing.

**UPDATE :**
It is working without errors when I remove `belongsTo` relation in `Member` and `Community` objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add the `belongsTo: Community` part to `Member` you are saying that `Member` will belong to a `Community`.

When you construct the `Member` object, you are not providing the `Community` that is connected with the `Member`. Committing the `Member` like this is blowing up because you haven't yet said the `Community` it belongs to.

You don't need those `save` calls there anyway, as `belongsTo` marks that `Community` will be responsible for the save. Take out the 3 m[x].save() lines, readd the `belongsTo` code and see if it works as expected.

Comment: Note: since `Bank` has the same relationship, remove the `com.save()` lines as well and let the `bank.save()` code commit it all.

Comment: Thanks for the explannation,  just keeping the `bankA.save(failOnError:true) and
  bankB.save(failOnError:true)` at the end 
  solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Its the order of object creation.  The belongsTo is going to create a foreign key relationship (at least by default), so you'd have to create the objects in the reverse order that you have them shown in your example (e.g. Bank, Community, Member).

You can also get into the constraints and mappings a little deeper to change some of the default mechanisms.  The Grails guide is fairly long, and at times I found it assumed a bit of previous knowledge of Hibernate, but it should have pretty much most of this (you may have to go down to the "Other" and "Advanced" topics).